# Link on navbar clears PHP Session

Tags: php, session

I have a weird bug that I'm not really sure how to describe, so let me know if this isn't clear.

I have a PHP site with authentication checks using a $_SESSION variable.

Flow goes:

Login Page -> Index Page -> Any page/Link not on navbar, works fine

However

Login Page -> Index Page -> click link on navbar -> $_SESSION["id"] clears and redirect to login

Then after this, it works fine.  I can use the navbar links normally with no issues.

This is replicated on multiple browsers (safari, chrome, firefox).  I tried setting the session_save_path directly already and there is no session_destroy called anywhere in the code, for testing.

This is the config.php that is included at the top of every page requiring authentication:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
{
    session_start();
    session_save_path("/home2/demundoi/tmp");
    session_regenerate_id();
}

// require authentication for most pages
if (!preg_match("{(?:login|logout|register_form)\.php$}", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]))
{   
    if (isset($_SESSION["id"]))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        //store what page user was trying to load
        $_SESSION["url"] = 'http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        redirect("login.php"); //parses relative or absolute path and outputs to html header
    }
}
```

Let me know if any other code would be relevant here.

Comment: An easy mistake to make is using absolute URLs in your links, e.g. putting `http://www.yourdomain.com` when your original login has been created on `http://yourdomain.com`. This will lose the session.

Comment: setting the path to "/" doesn't work?

Comment: Show your HTML so we can see the difference between the navbar and other links.

Comment: Thanks.. I feel dumb, I had "www" in the link.